# WCF JSON format

Tags: wcf, rest

I am writing some REST service in WCF. This is my code.

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public String ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Object Data { get; set; }
    public Result(String msg, Object data)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = msg;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

And I am calling this like this

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   UriTemplate = "login",
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
                   )]
        Result Login(string emailAddress, string password);
```

In my Interface implementation class, I write this.

```
public Result Login(string emailAddress, string password)
        {

            return new Result("[0000]",null);
        }
```

It gives me a JSON result like this

```
{"LoginResult":{"Data":null,"ErrorCode":"[0000]"}}
```

The weird thing is it has a LoginResult at the root,What I want is simply `{"Data":null,"ErrorCode":"[0000]"}` without this LoginResult header in JSON response. How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
I just noticed that you have two parameters in your method
1. string emailAddress
2. string password
```

Please **add these two parameters as properties in an object** and **use that object as the parameter**.
Then apply the changes as given below. This will work for you.

Please **change** your the following line:-

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

**To**

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought first. But when I changed it, It givems me this. "At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped."  Strage enough, I am using Bare for my other calls, and it looks ok...Just this Login...